# How to configure tomcat to request for credentials without authentication?

Tags: apache, authentication, tomcat, webserver

I need to get credentials from the client in web server (apache tomcat), but don't need to authenticate those users. Is it possible to configure so?

Comment: If you don't need authentication, then just put up a form asking for credentials. If you aren't performing authentication, though, I'm curious as to why you are requesting the credentials in the first place.

Comment: I need them in the web server, which works like a proxy. I used spring to get those credentials.

Comment: Just put up a form, then, and ask.